How do know which account are ReadonlySignedAccounts or ReadonlyUnsignedAccounts given a solana program transaction
I want to get the account that are UnsignedAccounts and SignedAccounts, can it be infered from the transaction below?
{
  "data": {
    "signatures": [
      {
        "0": 0,
        "1": 0,
        "2": 0,
        "3": 0,
        "4": 0,
        "5": 0,
        "6": 0,
        "7": 0,
        "8": 0,
        "9": 0,
        "10": 0,
        "11": 0,
        "12": 0,
        "13": 0,
        "14": 0,
        "15": 0,
        "16": 0,
        "17": 0,
        "18": 0,
        "19": 0,
        "20": 0,
        "21": 0,
        "22": 0,
        "23": 0,
        "24": 0,
        "25": 0,
        "26": 0,
        "27": 0,
        "28": 0,
        "29": 0,
        "30": 0,
        "31": 0,
        "32": 0,
        "33": 0,
        "34": 0,
        "35": 0,
        "36": 0,
        "37": 0,
        "38": 0,
        "39": 0,
        "40": 0,
        "41": 0,
        "42": 0,
        "43": 0,
        "44": 0,
        "45": 0,
        "46": 0,
        "47": 0,
        "48": 0,
        "49": 0,
        "50": 0,
        "51": 0,
        "52": 0,
        "53": 0,
        "54": 0,
        "55": 0,
        "56": 0,
        "57": 0,
        "58": 0,
        "59": 0,
        "60": 0,
        "61": 0,
        "62": 0,
        "63": 0
      }
    ],
    "message": {
      "header": {
        "numRequiredSignatures": 1,
        "numReadonlySignedAccounts": 0,
        "numReadonlyUnsignedAccounts": 2
      },
      "accountKeys": [
        "QAkyC4TN83zAYcRETJxK92aEVREqaDc3ejdtSuUjjfj",
        "6bmWX7G92w72uewtdbjJ898scxC4Mn1TQi9U2UnnFme6",
        "8S95TmSdzxQrG9tnppEdTqanwWjKtBFBLV1Rh96VTp6r",
        "cqYNVxjS7Xin1LmfM7KMwqKockNZpa4yiPkJ1L8ZvWN",
        "6kyAE2eHjdiupYVp9Qs6pjbq8Frk7G5deLAaW8tEtEBu",
        "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA"
      ],
      "recentBlockhash": "EPajeuQdGsf2qDA3rQsK8UpRX6V9GWPvcpwezTg5RaR8",
      "instructions": [
        {
          "programIdIndex": 4,
          "accounts": [0, 1, 3, 5, 2],
          "data": "xuVmYHgcsG7vwEpQSFFtT"
        }
      ],
      "indexToProgramIds": {}
    }
  }
}


I need to transform it like
AccountMeta(
        pubKey: pubKey,
        isWriteable: false,
        isSigner: isSigner,
      );


Certainly! In the accountKeys, the order goes:

writable signer accounts
readonly signer accounts
writable non-signer accounts
readonly non-signer accounts

And the "header" gives all the info to figure it out:
      "header": {
        "numRequiredSignatures": 1,      // total signers
        "numReadonlySignedAccounts": 0,  // subset of signers which are readonly
        "numReadonlyUnsignedAccounts": 2 // total readonly unsigned accounts
      },

So that gives:
      "accountKeys": [
        "QAkyC4TN83zAYcRETJxK92aEVREqaDc3ejdtSuUjjfj",  // writable signer
        "6bmWX7G92w72uewtdbjJ898scxC4Mn1TQi9U2UnnFme6", // writable unsigned
        "8S95TmSdzxQrG9tnppEdTqanwWjKtBFBLV1Rh96VTp6r", // writable unsigned
        "cqYNVxjS7Xin1LmfM7KMwqKockNZpa4yiPkJ1L8ZvWN",  // writable unsigned
        "6kyAE2eHjdiupYVp9Qs6pjbq8Frk7G5deLAaW8tEtEBu", // readonly unsigned
        "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA"   // readonly unsigned
      ],


ok, thank you   .
